# Python принимает значение False за 0

Tags: python, функции, list

```
def move_zeros(array):
    array_list = array
    if 0 in array_list:
        for _ in range(0, len(array_list)):
            array_list.remove(0)
            array_list.append(0)
    return array_list
```

Код принимает список любых значений и удаляет нули и возвращает их в конец этого списка, но когда в список попадает `False`, то он его удаляет так же как и ноль. Что можно сделать чтобы этого избежать?

Comment: `что можно сделать чтобы этого избежать?` - не хранить разнородные данные в списке

Comment: Написать свой False, написать свой оператор сравнения, много чего можно сделать. Выбор зависит от задачи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801854/how-to-ignore-false-so-it-doesnt-count-as-0  - как интересно. даже названия функций совпадают...

Comment: спасибо,использовал isinstance забыл про него

Comment: Само решение очень плохое, нужно его просто переписать на хорошее, а не дорабатывать напильником. У вас для каждого элемента массива будет выполнятся удаление нуля и его вставка. Даже если в массиве всего один ноль, а всего элементов - миллион, то код миллион раз удалит и вставит этот единственный несчастный ноль. Причём т.к. после первого раза этот ноль будет в конце списка, его удаление будет выполнятся со сложностью N. И в итоге весь алгоритм будет иметь квадратичную сложность. Это очень-очень не эффективный алгоритм. Нормальный алгоритм сейчас приведу в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

## Объяснение

Тип  `bool` наследуется от типа `int`, поэтому значение `False` равно `0`. Это означает, что вы можете отличить `0` от `False` с помощью дополнительной проверки типа, когда же одно только прямое сравнение не будет отличать `0` от `False`.

---

## Проверка типов

В данном случае, проверка типов должна быть устроена так:

```
type(value) is int
```

Потому что, `isinstance` сравнивает базовые классы, т.е. если `A` наследуются от `B`, то `isinstance(A(), B)` вернёт `True`, как и `isinstance(False, int)`

А при сравнении с помощью `type` мы проверяем именно текущий класс. Этим и будем пользоваться, т.к. `False` - `bool`, а `0` - `int` и `bool` не равен `int`!

---

## Решение

`remove` удаляет первое вхождение, поэтому даже с этой проверкой код не будет работать. Давайте просто использовать `del`

Моё решение таково:

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if value == 0 and type(value) is int:
            del array[i]
            array.append(0)
    return array


inp = [0, 1, 2, True, False, None, 0, '', [], (), {}, 0]

print(inp)
print(move_zeros(inp))
print(inp)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 2, True, False, None, 0, '', [], (), {}, 0]
[1, 2, True, False, None, '', [], (), {}, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, True, False, None, '', [], (), {}, 0, 0, 0]
```

Эта функция изменяет массив, и возвращает его

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы эта функция не влияла на массив, а создавала новый, то вы можете добавить `array = array[:]` в начало, так:

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    array = array[:]
    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if value == 0 and type(value) is int:
            del array[i]
            array.append(0)
    return array

...
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 2, True, False, None, 0, '', [], (), {}, 0]
[1, 2, True, False, None, '', [], (), {}, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, True, False, None, 0, '', [], (), {}, 0]
```

---

Ну и если же вам не нужно возвращать массив, а только изменять его, то удалите `return array` в конце:

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if value == 0 and type(value) is int:
            del array[i]
            array.append(0)

...
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 2, True, False, None, 0, '', [], (), {}, 0]
None
[1, 2, True, False, None, '', [], (), {}, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

## "O" большое

Алгоритм работает за `O(n)`, не учитывая, сколько работают встроенные функции питона. Но полагаю, что использованные функции работают тоже за `O(n)` или быстрее, не изменяя скорости алгоритма.

Ваш же алгоритм работает за `O(n^2)`, что медленнее `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот код не только различает 0 и False, но ещё и работает за линейное время, а не за квадрат, как ваш.

```
def move_zeros(data):

    num = len(data)
    data = [x for x in data if not(x == 0 and not isinstance(x, bool))]
    data.extend([0] * (num - len(data)))
    return data
```